# Bash build environment settings

Tags: bash, environment-variables, gcc, posix

I'm newbie in Bash and I'm using MinGW as a GCC compiler.

I have .profile in my home directory which sets building environment.
Here is .profile content.

What's a difference in commented/uncommented lines? Why GCC doesn't work with uncommented lines?

```
export LDFLAGS=-L/home/Toktik/lib
export CFLAGS=-I/home/Toktik/include
# export LDFLAGS=$LDFLAGS:/home/Toktik/lib/
# export CFLAGS=$CFLAGS:" -I/home/Toktik/include/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commented lines add new options and directories to the existing values of those variables. The uncommented lines overwrite the previous values of those variables.